# stative verb + now?

Tags: present-tense, present-simple, stative-verbs

In the present tense, I know that stative verbs usually don't work with present progressive. But what about stative verbs + now ?

For example, I'm hungry and I'm hungry now. I love you and I love you now. Do these sentences have differences meanings when adding now?

I think stative verbs without now seems relatively unchanging? I'm hungry (I have been hungry for a while and continue to be hungry). I'm hungry now (I'm hungry right now, it doesn't emphasize anything about the past and future). Am I correct? Thank you in advance

Comment: Just apply the relevant subsection of [Grice's maxims:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle) *Make your contribution as informative as is required (for the current purposes of the exchange), BUT **Do not** make your contribution more informative than is required.* In your cited context, it stands to reason that if you say you're hungry (you ***are*** hungry, Present Tense), you're referring to your ***current*** state, so ***now*** is unnecessary. If you ***do*** include it, the only possible reason is to contrast ***now*** with some other time (Past ***or*** Future).

Comment: (...when you ***weren't*** or ***won't be*** hungry! :)

Comment: Thanks for your replies @FumbleFingers , Do you mean that I'm hungry referring the current state and not suggesting anything more. But I was taught that present simple usually refers to habits, facts, or repeated things rather than the present. Is it used different for stative verbs?

Comment: If I said *I'm a human being*, that would only be meaningful in some context where my biological category was being contrasted with other entities that *weren't* humans. But I can't really think of any context where *I'm a human being **now*** would make sense, because I can't imagine how that could contrast with any past or future time when I wasn't or won't be human. But being hungry or not is something everyone can understand (not least because every human being *must* have experienced both states). So it's "meaningful" to append ***now*** to the assertion - you just need to ask *Why?*

Comment: ...that's to say, the concept of "stative verbs" isn't relevant here. It's the difference between *I'm going to work* and *I'm going to work **now*** - you have to have some *reason* to include the word ***now***, even if it's only to emphasize that you mean ***right now*** and not ***in five minutes from now.***

Comment: @Zelin *"But I was taught that present simple usually refers to habits, facts..."*  Isn't "I'm hungry" a fact?  I think you may be interpreting the lesson too broadly: the present tense doesn't mean "forever and unchanging", it simply means "is true now or generally".